# Register custom URI scheme handler in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, protocol, uri

In W7 and W8 I can execute an arbitrary executable from html just by registering handler in the registry as described https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/aa767914.aspx#app_reg

Similarly as **mailto**:someone@abc.com works.

The registration of handler in the registry does not suffice to get it to work in W10 though.

Have seen the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24455311/uri-scheme-launching and https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa767916.aspx but still not no definitive answer.
Anybody?

[image]

Comment: You never explained what happens and where you tested from? Generally, this looks fine.

Answer (score 1):

you set the "Default Icon" as key, but it should only be a string. This is the only difference i see. Attached a working version of my configuration (do connect rtsp with vlc).

kr stefan

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\rtsp]
"URL Protocol"=""
@="URL:Rtsp Streaming Protocol"
"DefaultIcon"="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc.exe\",1"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\rtsp\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\rtsp\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\rtsp\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc.exe\" \"%1\""
```

Comment: Not true. "DefaultIcon" is a key. But shouldn't matter anyway.